# What shoud I do with this eclipse error(html preview)?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

When I try to check my HTML code, I receive this error.
What should I do?
*'Starting HTTP Preview at localhost' has encountered a problem.

Port 8080 required by HTTP Preview at localhost is already in use. The Server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
*
[image]

I don't use and install Tomcat, Because I didn't study about jsp yet.

+My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: *To start this server you will need tostop the other process or change the port number(s).* - it tells you what to do

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 that your application is trying to use is already occupied by some other application. You have to close that application or use another port for your application.

To find which application is using port 8080, check this post [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the state of ports by the command `netstat -ano`, and you will see an item like this: `TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING  8940`, the last number is the pid of the process which is using the port 8080, you can use task manager to find the progress with this pid and kill it.